# Rails: Updating attributes after input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently trying to update the in_stock attribute in the wines controller. The in_stock attribute is also in the reservations controller.

When a user makes a reservation I pass the `wine.in_stock - @reservation.bottle` into the `reservation.in_stock` variable.

Now I need to update the `wine.in_stock` variable with the new `reservation.in_stock` variable.

I'm currently stuck at this level. Should I use `wine.update(in_stock: @reservation.in_stock)` or anything similar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices and they're slightly different. You can update attributes and then [`save`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save) or you can do that all at once with [`update`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update).

```
wine.in_stock = @reservation.in_stock
wine.save
```

This sets `wine.in_stock` in memory, then saves all changes to the object in the database. The advantage here is you might want to do a bunch of changes to `wine` and not save them until you're all done (or at all).

```
# Change `wine.in_stock` in memory only.
wine.in_stock = @reservation.in_stock

...some other code...

# Change `wine.appraisal` in memory only.
wine.appraisal = :good_enough_for_the_pope

...some other code...

# Change `wine.price` in memory only.
wine.price = 6000

...some other code...

# Save all changes to `wine` to the database.
wine.save
```

If you can make the changes all at once it's better to use `update`.

```
# Update and save `wine`.
wine.update(
  in_stock: @reservation.in_stock,
  appraisal: :good_enough_for_the_pope,
  price: 6000
)
```

This assigns all the attributes using `wine.in_stock=` and `wine.appraisal=` and `wine.price=`, and calls `wine.save` all in a single transaction.

Comment: Everything is working now! Thank you, another problem I recognized is that when I set the stock to 5 for example and someone orders 6 bottles, -1 gets stored in the in_stock attribute. Is there a way to validate that the integer is positiv before I update the attribute ?

Comment: @klasarn Yes, set up a [numericality validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) on stock with `only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0`. I recommend reading the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/) to learn the basics.